# How to use word boundry (\b) with regexp.MatchString() in go

Tags: regex, go, word-boundary

I am using a function regexp.matchString() to match regex pattern to my string. I have to use word boundary in order to find exact match. For example, I want to match "compute" but not "computer". The problem is my string will have both "compute" and "computer". So I want to use word boundary. I tried using \b in couple of online go-regex tester and it worked. However, \b does not seem to work for regexp.matchString() function. Does anyone know if there is an alternate to \b? or how can I get expected result?
My code

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    brandName := "home;compute furniture;computer"
    filterVal := "(?i)compute\b"
    regexMatch, _ := regexp.MatchString(filterVal, brandName)
    fmt.Println(regexMatch)
}
```

This function returns me false when I use \b. Please help

Comment: I haven't played with regex in Go yet, but the common problem here is the ```\``` being used as an escape character both for strings and for the regex engine. It's probably being gobbled up by the string so the regex engine never sees it. Try double escaping?

Comment: Thank you Adam Smith. solution from Anar-G worked perfectly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double quotes often swallow the `\`. Always use [raw strings](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) with regexps, SQL, and such.

```
filterVal := `(?i)compute\b`
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/ePzZf5uLtw.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Ainar-G for such a quick reply. It worked perfectly.

Comment: enclose the backslash in triple backticks to make the formatting work. In a strange parallel to the question being asked! :)